# Suggestions about Lightweight Open Source Web Servers which can support Web Services written in Java

Tags: java, web-services, open-source, jakarta-ee, webserver

I am currently looking for Lightweight open source web servers which can support Web Services written in Java.

My basic requirement is that it should occupy as much less RAM as possible at runtime and should support Web Services written in Java.

The target number of concurrent users is around 100-150.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for an application server (e.g. Glassfish) or merely a servlet container (e.g. Tomcat)?

Comment: I am basically looking for a server which has low memory footprint, is open source and supports Web services written in Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is an open-source application server that is embeddable (i.e. it has a low memory footprint as it runs on mobile phones, etc.).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Would like to know that does it support Web services written in Java?

Comment: Yes, jetty is a java servlet container which is embeddable to your webapp. I have only seen people use it for testing purpose. I don't know how well it performs as a service.

Comment: As far as I know, Google uses Jetty for AppEngine so it's performance can't be too shabby.

Answer (score 2):

I found tomcat very handy. It is easy to install, deploy your webapp and fairly stable. All java servlet containers come with initial minimal RAM setting which is almost always not enough and you will have to change maximum RAM setting yourself.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the memory footprint for tomcat...?

Comment: I have tried to mornitor my tomcat memory once, it kept going up close to maximum and then went down. This is normal behaviour of Java garbage collection. You many want to set the garbage collection scheme for your tomcat server. I added class unloading as well since I have a lot of classes and it causes my permanant memory generation full.

Comment: If you are worry about memory leak in tomcat, I don't know. There are a few features in tomcat, e.g. catche, which I beleive that it can cause large memory consumption. But you are probably not going to use it anyway. It is probably common problem for other servlet container. (these are just my opinion so feel free to find out more)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy web services in a desktop application and you are looking for embedded server, you can use the `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` that is comes as part of J2SE6. Check it out.
It is very easy to deploy web services via the `Endpoint`.
And is part of Java so you will have no dependencies with third-party libraries.
Another option is Jetty (Apache)

Answer (score 0):

Not so lightweight, but I found glassfish easy to setup and get running. All I had to do was create a EJB3 bean using annotations and the web service was done. Really simple. This was for a proof of concept so would take more to do as a proper setup.